# Oracle PL/SQL Check whether DB Link exists and works

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-connection, execute

I want to have a function which checks whether a database link specified by a name string exists and works. I'm stuck at writing an exception, I don't know how to catch the error codes.

```
create or replace function CHECK_DB_LINK(dbLink IN VARCHAR2) RETURN int IS
  stmt VARCHAR2(99) ;
BEGIN
  stmt := 'select 1 from dual@' || dbLink;
  execute immediate stmt;
  return 1;
EXCEPTION  -- exception handlers begin

-- Only one of the WHEN blocks is executed.

   WHEN 2019 THEN  
      dbms_output.put_line('Caught exception');
      return 0;
END;
/
set serveroutput on;
DECLARE 
   c int; 
BEGIN 
   c := CHECK_DB_LINK('X');
   dbms_output.put_line('Connection '||'X'||' successful: ' || c); 
END; 

ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found
ORA-06512: at "CONFIGURATION.CHECK_DB_LINK", line 5
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch a specific error by declaring an exception variable and linking it to that error code; e.g.:

```
create or replace function CHECK_DB_LINK(dbLink IN VARCHAR2) RETURN int IS
  stmt VARCHAR2(99) ;
  no_such_link EXCEPTION;
  pragma exception_init(no_such_link, -2019);
BEGIN
  stmt := 'select 1 from dual@' || dbLink;
  execute immediate stmt;
  return 1;
EXCEPTION 
  WHEN no_such_link THEN  
    dbms_output.put_line('Caught exception');
    return 0;
END;
/
```

[Read more.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/plsql-error-handling.html#GUID-4F0787E6-ABCA-4860-A28E-435C7FE15154)

Your anonymous block will then see:

```
Caught exception
Connection X successful: 0


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

If any other error is raised then it will not be caught (as it would be using `with others`), and the caller would see that exception - and be able to handle it or pass it along.

You might want your function to explicltly catch and handle other errors - if the link exists but the credentials are wrong, for instance - and you can define additional exceptions for those, with appropriate pragmas, so you catch those in their own `when` blocks and return an appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around to catching specific exceptions, I just catch all other exceptions:

```
create or replace function CHECK_DB_LINK(dbLink IN VARCHAR2) RETURN int IS
  stmt VARCHAR2(99) ;
BEGIN
  stmt := 'select 1 from dual@' || dbLink;
  execute immediate stmt;
  return 1;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN  
      -- dbms_output.put_line('Caught exception');
      return 0;
END;
```

Comment: Maybe use `dbms_output.put_line(SQLERRM);`